# how to convert raw webservice message soapenv string into related object in CXF preferable

Tags: web-services, cxf, marshalling, unmarshalling

i have a webservice raw message like as string. My objective is to alter this message contenct preferable like Goodbye!! to AlteredGoodbye!!.
Let me know is there any api/utils methods which does this work. I am using jboss 5 with cxf stack, hence preffering cxf utils for this.

RAW XML STRING

Goodbye!!

Answer (score 0):

You have to add an [out interceptor](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/interceptors.html)

For example :

```
public class SoapActionOutInterceptor extends AbstractSoapInterceptor {

   public SoapActionOutInterceptor() {
         super(Phase.POST_LOGICAL);
   }

   public void handleMessage(SoapMessage message) throws Fault {
         if (message.getVersion() instanceof Soap11) {
                PocBean pb = null;
                MessageContentsList list = (MessageContentsList) message.getContent(List.class);
                for (Iterator itList = list.iterator(); itList.hasNext();) {
                       Object content = itList.next();
                       if (content instanceof PocBean) {
                              pb = (PocBean) content;
                              pb.setParam1("AlteredGoodbye!!");

                       }
                }
         }
   }
}
```

and declare this interceptor like this :

```
       <jaxws:endpoint id="pocWebService" implementor="#pocService"
         address="/pocService">

         <jaxws:properties>
                <entry key="schema-validation-enabled" value="true" />
         </jaxws:properties>
         <jaxws:outInterceptors>
                <bean class="fr.genybet.service.interceptor.SoapActionOutInterceptor" />
         </jaxws:outInterceptors>
   </jaxws:endpoint>
```